# How to list sum of values in the specific period

Tags: sql-server, query, sum, operator

Sorry for very newbie questions. I have a table, shown below with values about duration of events. Sometimes I have several events in one hour/day. Instead of showing each particular event, I would like ot have sum of duration of all events on hourly/daily basis. How to achieve that?

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[switches]
WHERE previousevent='on' 
AND friendlyname='BathroomLight'
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

[image]

Comment: Please remove the image and add data as text. Include the expected result as well. [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: something like, I've not created a table and inserted test data so it's not tested.


SELECT DATETRUNC(hour, timestamp), sum(duration), count(duration) 
from dbo.switches
WHERE previousevent='on' 
AND friendlyname='BathroomLight'
group by DATETRUNC(hour, timestamp)

If you're not running SQL 2022 and therefore don't have datetrunc use

left(convert(varchar(30, timestamp, 120), 13)
.
instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to provide example DDL and DML when asking these sorts of questions. This let's folks reproduce your data set quickly and easily.
Here's a method that does that, and generates some random data to put in to it. Feel free to use it in your next question, or to add some data to this one.

```
DECLARE @switches TABLE (DeviceID NVARCHAR(10), FriendlyName NVARCHAR(50), Core NVARCHAR(10), Location NVARCHAR(20), Room NVARCHAR(20), Event NVARCHAR(3), 
                         PreviousEvent NVARCHAR(3), PreviousEventTime DATETIME, Timestamp DATETIME, ID INT IDENTITY, Duration INT)


INSERT INTO @switches (DeviceID, FriendlyName, Core, Location, Room, Event, PreviousEvent, PreviousEventTime, Timestamp,  Duration)
SELECT TOP 200 '10008c937d', 'BathroomLight', 'main', 'Poppeska', 'Bathroom', 'off', 'on', 
        DATEADD(SECOND,ROUND((20000 - 2000) * RAND(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT) + 0),0),GETUTCDATE()), 
        DATEADD(SECOND,ROUND((20000 - 2000) * RAND(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT) + 0),0),GETUTCDATE()), 
        ROUND((2000 - 0) * RAND(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT) + 0),0)
  FROM sys.sysobjects
```

You may need to adjust this to match your specific data set.

Now on to your question. You could just run a aggregate query over the table:

```
SELECT s.DeviceID, s.FriendlyName, s.Core, s.Location, s.Event, DATEPART(HOUR,s.Timestamp) AS hour, CAST(s.Timestamp AS DATE) AS Date, COUNT(*) AS EventCount, AVG(s.Duration) AS AverageDuration
  FROM @switches s
 GROUP BY s.DeviceID, s.FriendlyName, s.Core, s.Location, s.Event, DATEPART(HOUR,s.Timestamp), CAST(s.Timestamp AS DATE)
 ORDER BY Date DESC, Hour DESC
```

```
DeviceID    FriendlyName    Core    Location    Event   hour    Date        EventCount  AverageDuration
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10008c937d  BathroomLight   main    Poppeska    off     2       2023-01-05  5           948
10008c937d  BathroomLight   main    Poppeska    off     1       2023-01-05  31          1206
10008c937d  BathroomLight   main    Poppeska    off     0       2023-01-05  47          927
10008c937d  BathroomLight   main    Poppeska    off     23      2023-01-04  47          950
10008c937d  BathroomLight   main    Poppeska    off     22      2023-01-04  36          1037
10008c937d  BathroomLight   main    Poppeska    off     21      2023-01-04  34          910
```

But, if there are no rows for a particular hour you won't get that row back at all. Let's say there were no events between 22:00:00 and 22:59:59 on 2023-01-04, there would be no row at all for that date and hour.

To get around that you can setup a range CTE using the min and max dates from your table:

```
;WITH Hours AS (
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-DATEPART(MILLISECOND,@start),DATEADD(SECOND,-DATEPART(SECOND,@start),DATEADD(MINUTE,-DATEPART(MINUTE,@start),@start))) AS hour
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,1,hour)
  FROM Hours
 WHERE HOUR < @end
)

SELECT s.DeviceID, s.FriendlyName, s.Core, s.Location, s.Event, h.hour, COUNT(*) AS EventCount, AVG(s.Duration) AS AverageDuration
  FROM Hours h
    INNER JOIN @switches s
      ON s.Timestamp BETWEEN h.hour AND DATEADD(HOUR,1,h.hour)
 WHERE PreviousEvent = 'On'
   AND FriendlyName = 'BathroomLight'
 GROUP BY s.DeviceID, s.FriendlyName, s.Core, s.Location, s.Event, h.hour
 ORDER BY h.hour DESC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

```
DeviceID    FriendlyName    Core    Location    Event   hour                    EventCount  AverageDuration
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10008c937d  BathroomLight   main    Poppeska    off     2023-01-05 02:00:00.000 5           948
10008c937d  BathroomLight   main    Poppeska    off     2023-01-05 01:00:00.000 31          1206
10008c937d  BathroomLight   main    Poppeska    off     2023-01-05 00:00:00.000 47          927
10008c937d  BathroomLight   main    Poppeska    off     2023-01-04 23:00:00.000 47          950
10008c937d  BathroomLight   main    Poppeska    off     2023-01-04 22:00:00.000 36          1037
10008c937d  BathroomLight   main    Poppeska    off     2023-01-04 21:00:00.000 34          910
```

This generates a row for each hour in the table, and then aggregates by those. If there are no rows in the table you will still get a row back, with appropriate aggregates.